# finding the missing variables in a df and print out the name of variable

Tags: r

If I want to check whether my df have all the variables I need, how can I identify the missing variables and print the warning message.

Currently I have:

```
  if (!all(c("test", "result","Unit") %in% colnames(data))) {
      print("'test', 'result', 'Unit' are needed in this data set. Check data again.")
      
    } else{
      print("Everything is OK")
    }
```

I would like to be able  to print out the missing one instead of `'test', 'result', 'Unit' are needed in this data set. Check data again.` Any suggestion?

Comment: How can I identify the missing variable? `!all(c("test", "result","Unit") %in% colnames(data))` gave me the result whether I missed one or more variable. How can I find which one is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Data

```
complete_names <- c("a","b","c","d","z")

example_names <- c("a","b","c","q","y")
```

### Code

```
diff_names1 <- setdiff(complete_names,example_names)

n1 <- length(diff_names1)

diff_names2 <- setdiff(example_names,complete_names)

n2 <- length(diff_names2)


if(n1 > 0 | n2 > 0) {
  
  necessary_variables <- ""

  extra_variables <- ""
  
  are_is <- ifelse(n1 == 1," is"," are")
  
  if(n1 > 0 ){
    
    necessary_variables <- paste0(paste0(diff_names1,collapse = ", "),are_is," needed in this data set. Check data again.")
    
  }
  
  if(n2 > 0 ){
    
    extra_variables <- paste0("Sample has extra variables: ",paste0(diff_names2,collapse = ", "))
    
  } 
  
  cat(necessary_variables,"\n",extra_variables)
  
} else{
  print("Everything is OK")
}
```

### Output

```
  d, z are needed in this data set. Check data again. 
 Sample has extra variables: q, y
```

Comment: `setdiff(x,y)` is finding those elements in x but not in y. what if I want to know the real difference? If we add `"q"` in `example_names`, then is it possible for us to find, `d,z are not in sample, and sample have extra variable q`?

Comment: @Stataq I did not make the best solution, but it works. Just updated my answer

Comment: Pretty good! Thanks for the updated one. One silly question, is it a way to control `are` or `is` based on how many variables are missing?